# How to call/retrieve getTokenSilent in react.js after token is received from auth0

Tags: reactjs, graphql, auth0, react-apollo

Hope someone can help me. I am using react, apollo, auth0, graphql

The problem (lack of knowledge) is that I cannot find any info on how I can call the `getTokenSilently` after a user login.

The bearer token is received and is correct from auth0 after login. I check on graphiql and jwt.io.

Also in `auth0Service.js` I have the

```
getTokenSilently: (...p) => auth0Client.getTokenSilently(...p),
```

So far all is good.

But now I need to call this token (I don't want `localStorage`) but I do not know how.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Auth0 React SDk.

Their docs show how to use getAccessTokenSilently()

https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-react#call-an-api